# Await task not working when triggered by code but if by user, it works

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library

I have application for controlling LED strip. UI has combobox with effect selection and when user selects mode, it waits for currently running effect loop to finish by calling StopTask() and then executes selected effect. It sends LED color etc. to Arduino via serial. This works.

Problem is when I trigger StopTask() by MainWindow_OnClosing (when user exits the application), it triggers StopTask() but gets stuck on await currentEffectMode. I will try to explain it more by comments inside the code

MainWindow mode selection:

```
private void CbMode_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Checkbox selection triggers this
    _ledStrip.LightModes.ChangeMode(CbMode.SelectedIndex);
}

private void MainWindow_OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // Trigger disconnect and wait for success - this doesn't work (explained below in code comments)
    _ledStrip.LightModes.Disconnect().Wait();
}
```

Light modes class:

```
private Task _modeTask;
private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
// This is being triggered by change mode
internal async void ChangeMode(int mode)
{
    // It waits for current loop to finish
    await StopTask();
    switch (mode)
    {
        case (int)Modes.Static:
            // Then assigns new one
            _modeTask = Static(_cancellationToken.Token);
            break;
        case (int)Modes.Breath:
            _modeTask = Breath(_cancellationToken.Token);
            break;
    }
}

internal async Task StopTask()
{
    if (_modeTask == null)
        return;

    // Set cancellation token to cancel
    _cancellationToken.Cancel();
    try
    {
        // and wait for task to finish. This works if triggered by user interaction BUT this is where it gets stuck when called by Disconnect() method (below). It awaits here forever
        await _modeTask;
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        // After sucessful await create new cts
        _cancellationToken.Dispose();
        _cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }
}

// Example of LED effect loop
internal async Task Static(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (true)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        _ledStrip.FillLedsWithColor();

        // Wait for strip to light up    
        await LightLeds();
        // Delay before next loop round
        await Task.Delay(15, cancellationToken);
    }
}

// This is being called by window onclosing
internal async Task Disconnect()
{
    //Stop current task and close serial connection. _device is serial
    await StopTask();
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        if (_device.IsOpen())
        {
            _device.Clear();
            _device.Close();
        }
    });
}

// Method for sending LED information to Arduino
internal async Task LightLeds()
{
    if (!_device.IsOpen())
        return;

    await Task.Run(() => 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < StaticValues.NumLeds; i++)
        {
            _device.Send((byte)i, _ledStrip.Leds[i].LedColor.R, _ledStrip.Leds[i].LedColor.G, _ledStrip.Leds[i].LedColor.B);
        }
        _device.LightUp();
    });
}
```

I am beginner with Tasks and I am pretty sure that I am not using them properly (some of them are certainly unnecessary but I don't know it) and maybe it's the reason why it's not working. I tried to search and found many examples for using Tasks but I still don't understand it well.

Thank you!

Comment: Try making your 'MainWindow_OnClosing' async void instead, and await Disconnect instead of calling. Wait()

Comment: BTW your CbMode_OnSelectionChanged should really also be similar, and then make ChangeMode async Task.

Comment: [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: Thank you, it was really this simple! Btw. do you think my other awaits and tasks are ok? Aren't there any unnecessary things?

Thank you for that article too

Comment: If you're new to async and it works and you have no calls to .Wait() or .Result, no methods that have an async void signature, except for event handlers (like yours), no compiler warnings, you're probably on the right track. Having no Task.Run()s is also something to aim for, but sometimes it's needed (as in your case, assuming the Arduino SDK does not provide async methods). Obviously this is just a very rough yardstick; ultimately if you want to use async correctly in anger, you really need to (read and) understand it well at quite a low level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `MainWindow_OnClosing()` to be `async void` instead, and use `await Disconnect()` instead of calling `.Wait()`. Event handlers are almost the only async methods for which this acceptable; the rest should have an `async Task[<T>]` signature instead. (There are some exceptions to the async part, but not the Task part, but I won’t muddy the waters with that here).  This will stop you blocking (see link in Dmytro’s comment for more).

While there, change `CbMode_OnSelectionChanged()` to be similar (`async void`), make `ChangeMode()` `async Task`, and `await` it instead.

The only other minor thing of note is that if you move the device-closing code into your event handler instead (or refactor it into another method that you call from the event handler, after `await Disconnect()`), you should not need the `Invoke()`, as async event handlers - done correctly - give you this for free; i.e. effectively remaining on the UI thread while not blocking.  (I’m assuming that’s what you trying to achieve there?)

Comment: Thank you!
_device is just serial port communication.
That invoke is there because I was trying to fix another thing - _device.Clear() should send #000000 to all leds (like turn off everything) - but I still haven't fixed it yet. I was trying everything from running it in Task.Run(), this Invoke, normal execute...
It is reaching that send to serial port command but when window is closed, all leds remains on. Maybe it executes _device.Close() (classic serial port close) before it sends that data? I have _device.Write(), .Clear() ... as a normal public void. Is it wrong?

Comment: The serial port stuff is a getting away from the question a bit, but if you have async options for that, and you're in an async context already, it would usually make sense to use those.  If you only have sync options, you probably only want to bother wrapping those in a `Task.Run()` if they are not already very quick (I would imagine what you're doing is only a few ms), and them running on a different (arbitrary) thread is not a problem.

Comment: I thought this is still related to async / await so I didn't want to create another question.
But I solved it now. It was my poor mistake, I was sending only #000000 data to LEDs but I have forgot to send LightUp command after that.
Anyway thank you very much!